# Display the name of the user currently logged in?

Tags: user-accounts

Is there a way (without SP Designer) that I can display the name of the user that is currently logged in on my team's homepage?

Comment: What sharepoint version are you referring?
Do you have the freedom to deploy any custom components?

Comment: Hi Vivek, I'm using MOSS 2007 Basic. If you are talking about Server Installed components then no; if you mean custom webparts through CEWPs/uploading .dwps etc then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the current user object to get the name:

SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name